# Need to connect ruspberry pi2 with electrical switch board

Tags: home-automation

Need to connect ruspberry pi2 with my home electrical switch board to achieve home automation system i.e. light switch on/off , fan dimmer etc. I grab the ruspberry pi2 board along with relay module . So can someone give some insights how can i do this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dome this . I followed the steps from the below URL
https://www.trafex.nl/2014/08/25/connect-a-relay-board-to-your-raspberry-pi/ 
and its worked just fine.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more informations about your relay module?
If you are using a Sainsmart module, this instructions will help you:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=36225